# Is there any easy and simple way to reduce the size of MP3 files?

Tags: audio, mp3, filesize

I create mobile apps, and use lots of MP3 files in my mobile apps. But, I am not an audio engineer.

Would anyone please tell me if there's any easy and simple way to reduce the size of MP3 files ? (In other words, are there any free or simple software tools that can reduce the MP3 file size ?)

---

(PS: I am new to this site. Please excuse me if this question does not fit the guideline of the site. Thanks.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way.

Compression via mp3 removes frequencies, people tend „not to hear“. This reduces the amount of data to be stored. Compared to raw data (.wav) mp3 are considerably smaller.

If you try to zip a mp3 file, you won‘t save many bytes, if any.

What you could do is to resample mp3 audio at a lower rate, at the cost of loss in audio quality.

Comment: In case the OP doesn't realise, you have to compress from the original uncompressed audio.